# Differences between trailer and the Endgame movie

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, trailers, avengers-endgame

Marvel has a habit of putting differences in their trailers compared to the movies (E.g. Not showing Thor missing an eye in the Infinity War trailer).

Were there any for *Avengers: Endgame* and if so, what were they?

Comment: i don't recall anything specific. Since  they avoided spoiling pretty much *anything* in the trailers they probably thought it unnecessary.

Comment: Spoiler ahead: I do not have proof, but I have the feeling that in the movie where we see a prime shot of Cap America face (when he's battling thanos), in the movie you can see AntMan in the background as a giant. That is not the case in the trailer (The second trailer shows Cap. America face in the screen, but nothing is seen in the background). But No proof to confirm, until the movie comes out in decent quality

Comment: There's also a shot of Rocket opening a door in Norway, in the movie you can see Hulk in the background, in the trailer you can't. Plus in the shot where ant-man comes back, in the trailer Natasha has short blonde hair, in the movie it's long and red. And some shots from the trailer were  unused (IIRC Nebula looking at Tony in the doorframe of the benotaur, Natasha's shooting practice at Avengers HQ). - I'm sure someone will compile everything into a real answer with screenshots from the trailers ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just saw it fresh in the theatre, so I hope my memory won't fail me. I'll try to put the major ones in spoiler tags and mentioned when I'm not sure. All of these are from trailers and they don't happen in the movie.

## [Marvel Studios' Avengers: Endgame](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hA6hldpSTF8&list=PLK5HARgNfgj95eUGZzMZ90J0Fjom58eRj&index=17&t=0s) (Trailer 1)

### Captain crying at [01:13](https://youtu.be/hA6hldpSTF8?list=PLK5HARgNfgj95eUGZzMZ90J0Fjom58eRj)

[image: Captain crying]

Didn't happen AFAIK

---

### Hallway shot at [01:20](https://youtu.be/hA6hldpSTF8?list=PLK5HARgNfgj95eUGZzMZ90J0Fjom58eRj&t=80)

[image: Hallway shot]

Shown multiple times. Multiple people edited out. I won't mention it in following trailers again.

---

### Nebula standing on a ship at [01:24](https://youtu.be/hA6hldpSTF8?list=PLK5HARgNfgj95eUGZzMZ90J0Fjom58eRj&t=84)

[image: Nebula]

Can't remember this scene, but not sure.

---

### Scott doesn't say: "Can you buzz me in?" at [02:20](https://youtu.be/hA6hldpSTF8?list=PLK5HARgNfgj95eUGZzMZ90J0Fjom58eRj&t=139)

[image: Ant-Man]

---

## [Big Game TV Spot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-iFq6IcAxBc&list=PLK5HARgNfgj95eUGZzMZ90J0Fjom58eRj&index=16&t=0s)

### Black Widow practicing at shooting range at [00:17](https://youtu.be/-iFq6IcAxBc?list=PLK5HARgNfgj95eUGZzMZ90J0Fjom58eRj&t=17)

[image: Black Widow]

This scene is in multiple trailers. Didn't happen and I won't mention it in the following trailers.

---

### Captain America strapping shield at [00:20](https://youtu.be/-iFq6IcAxBc?list=PLK5HARgNfgj95eUGZzMZ90J0Fjom58eRj&t=20)

[image: Shield time]

Minor spoiler:

> At this point, he had an injury on his arm which was edited out.

---

## [Marvel Studios' Avengers: Endgame](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcMBFSGVi1c&list=PLK5HARgNfgj95eUGZzMZ90J0Fjom58eRj&index=15&t=0s) (Trailer 2)

This is the one with scenes from previous films with highlighted red colour. It also has plenty of lines, which were not said in the film.

### Iron Man never said this at [00:03](https://youtu.be/TcMBFSGVi1c?list=PLK5HARgNfgj95eUGZzMZ90J0Fjom58eRj&t=3)

> It seems like a thousand years ago. I fought my way out of that cave.
>   Became Iron Man, realized I loved you

---

### This was also not said at [00:28](https://youtu.be/TcMBFSGVi1c?list=PLK5HARgNfgj95eUGZzMZ90J0Fjom58eRj&t=28)

> The world has changed. None of us can go back, what we can do is our best and 
>   sometimes the best we can do is to start over.

---

### Neither was this one at [01:00](https://youtu.be/TcMBFSGVi1c?list=PLK5HARgNfgj95eUGZzMZ90J0Fjom58eRj&t=60)

> I saw all these people die

---

### Hawkeye running at [01:26](https://youtu.be/TcMBFSGVi1c?list=PLK5HARgNfgj95eUGZzMZ90J0Fjom58eRj&t=86)

[image: Hawkguy]

This is also a recurring scene.
**MAJOR SPOILER:**

> I think in the movie he ran with Infinity Gauntlet in hand.

---

### Whatever it takes at [01:38](https://youtu.be/TcMBFSGVi1c?list=PLK5HARgNfgj95eUGZzMZ90J0Fjom58eRj&t=98)

Only Captain America and Black Widow say it out loud in the movie.
Also a recurring one.

---

### Thor summoning Stormbreaker at [02:20](https://youtu.be/TcMBFSGVi1c?list=PLK5HARgNfgj95eUGZzMZ90J0Fjom58eRj&t=140)

[image: Fight]

He doesn't smile afterwards. You can check the full scene in another [TV Spot](https://youtu.be/9QbltzIUV6w?list=PLK5HARgNfgj95eUGZzMZ90J0Fjom58eRj&t=61)

---

## [Marvel Studios’ Avengers: Endgame | Special Look](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCSNFZKbhZE)

### Rhodey didn't say this at [00:05](https://youtu.be/KCSNFZKbhZE?t=5)

> Yeah because he killed all our friends?

---

### No Black Widow in the rain at [00:07](https://youtu.be/KCSNFZKbhZE?t=7)

[image: All by myself]

---

### Captain on the ground at [00:45](https://youtu.be/KCSNFZKbhZE?t=45)

[image: Why do we fall, Master Bruce?]

**MAJOR SPOILER:**

> At this point, Captain shield was broken.

Answer (score 5):

There were lots of differences between the trailer and the movie. Some of which are as follows.

Warning: it has spoilers.

### 1. Avengers marching.

In the 2nd trailer, we see that Avengers marching wearing quantum suits. This scene was missing in the movie. They don't really march.

### 2. Missing Hulk

Hulk's appearance was kept secret this time. We see only Bruce Banner not Hulk. In Infinity War trailer, we saw Hulk on Wakanda, but not in the movie. This time they didn't show Hulk, but Hulk is in the movie.

### 3. Cap's shield

Captain America's shield is shown intact in the trailer, but it is broken during that sequence.

### 4. Hawkeye running away from an explosion

We see Hawkeye running from explosion holding infinity gauntlet, but this particular scene doesn't appear in the movie.

### 5. Natasha practicing

We see Natasha AKA Black Widow in the trailer target practicing and punching bags. However, these scenes didn't make it into the movie.

### 6. Missing Pepper Potts

When Tony arrives on earth, Avengers were waiting for him along with Pepper Potts, but the trailer doesn't show her.

<sub>[Source 1](https://www.gamespot.com/gallery/avengers-endgame-all-the-trailer-scenes-that-weren/2900-2739/), [Source 2](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2019/04/avengers-endgame-trailer-movie-differences)</sub>